# AMP Cache cant load jpg pictures

Tags: caching, amp-html, accelerated-mobile-page

I just started my first AMP Project and want to enable the cache function.
So I found this webpage ([amp converter](https://ampbyexample.com/advanced/using_the_google_amp_cache/)). When I call the converted link my amp-img won't be shown. I host my website on firebase but I dont think this could be a problem.
My code is on [github](https://github.com/Gnadi/TestumgebungWeb).

The converted link is (https://neverforget--1b1ca-firebaseapp-com.cdn.ampproject.org/c/s/neverforget-1b1ca.firebaseapp.com/)

And the original is (https://neverforget-1b1ca.firebaseapp.com/)

My amp-img looks like this:

```
<amp-img src="kek.jpg" width="1208" height="790" layout="responsive"></amp-img>
```

I am a little bit confused but when I enable the google cache will this enable the google amp viewer on mobile devices for my webpage?